# Chef template rewrites file even though content didn't change

Tags: chef

I'm using [template](https://docs.chef.io/templates.html) to generate a file. When the app on the server starts, it re-writes the file - the content doesn't change, but Chef considers it as changed and during next run it re-writes it as well. In log it says `no diff` during `template` processing and then triggers the notifiers.

What can I do to make Chef compare the files by content so that it doesn't notifies services to restart without a real reason.

Comment: Maybe attributes (`chmod`?). Pasting the `-l debug` output could also help.

Comment: Could also be change in ownership.

Comment: @StephenKing thx. found error in debug mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug Log:

```
DEBUG:calculating checksum of file1 to compare with c24f2aa74f9665cb944ab72ed34571367a0de38e10432675d3c5e8610ad9d046  
DEBUG: running: diff -u file1 file2
```

Thus checksums are not equal even though diff (in chef) returns **(no diff)**. Then I tried to run `diff -u file1 file2` in terminal result:
**\ No newline at end of file**

So the difference in size of files is 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

Template resources manage not only the contents but the `group`, `owner`, and `mode` of the file.  If the contents are not changing, as you note, then you'll want to take a close look at those other attributes, because a change in any of them will still trigger the notifications.